# php mysqli insert multiple rows to 1 table and 1 row to another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been working on this with help from this site. I can now insert into `players` table multiple rows (based on `$add-rows` value). I need to, also, insert into the `events` table 1 row. when I submit the form, it inserts into `players` fine but not into `events`

This is my form with all values needed for 2 queries

```
<form id="form-add" name="form-add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page.php">
<input name="add-name" id="add-name" type="text" value="Event">
<input name="add-start" id="add-start" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-end" id="add-end" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-loc" id="add-loc" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-rows" id="add-rows" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-submit" id="add-submit" type="submit" value="Add" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>
```

These are the values I'm posting from the form

```
<?php
$add_name = $_POST['add-name'];
$add_start = $_POST['add-start'];
$add_end = $_POST['add-end'];
$add_loc = $_POST['add-loc'];
$add_rows = $_POST['add-rows'];
$add_url = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($add_start)).'-'.str_replace('-',' ',($add_name));

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) { //check if form submitted
    //connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name');

    //this is the first query - to insert multiple rows in to players table (from same form)
    $query  = "INSERT INTO players (position, event, start, end, name, one, two, three, four, five, six) 
        VALUES ('', '$add_url', '$add_start', '$add_end', '', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No');" .
        str_repeat(", ('', '$add_url', '$add_start', '$add_end', '', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No')", $add_rows - 1);

    //this is the 2nd query - to insert to events table (from same form)
    $query .= "INSERT INTO events (ur, name, start, end, loc) VALUES ('$add_url', '$add_name' '$add_start', '$add_end', '$add_loc');";

    // execute query - $result is false if the first query failed
    $result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query);

    if ($result) {
        do {
            // grab the result of the next query
            if (($result = mysqli_store_result($mysqli)) === false && mysqli_error($mysqli) != '') {
                echo "Query failed: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        } while (mysqli_more_results($mysqli) && mysqli_next_result($mysqli)); // while there are more results
    } else {
        echo "First query failed..." . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
}//end of form submit if
?>
```

Comment: @Your Common Sense i need to enter x number of rows bcz don't have the names (name column in players table) . those will be updated later. but need the x number of slots (rows). about multi_query, i tried it and no luck. i can insert to players table but not events. i'm going thru my code now.. debugging as u suggested but no luck yet. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main faults with your code

1. You are using `mysqli_multi_query()` which is useless here and only makes your code overcomplicated.
2. You are not using placeholders, which makes your code vulnerable to injection
3. You are inserting identical rows in your database, which is a crime against database laws.

So, make 2 queries: one inserts 1 record into players table and another - 1 into events.
Run them in 2 separate calls using prepared statements.
As mysqli is unusable with them - use PDO instead.